# CyberSource HOP - Recurring vs Installment

Tags: drupal

I am trying to implement CyberSource HOP since few days. I have followed the guide given at their website. However no matter what I do the payment always shows up as "installment" instead of "recurring" at the CyberSource business center.

see the fields I am sending:

```
orderPage_transactionType = 'authorization, subscription'
amount = *
currency = 'usd'
orderPage_timestamp = *
merchantID = *
orderPage_signaturePublic = *
orderPage_version = 4
orderPage_serialNumber = *
recurringSubscriptionInfo_amount = *
recurringSubscriptionInfo_numberOfPayments = 12
recurringSubscriptionInfo_frequency = 'monthly'
recurringSubscriptionInfo_automaticRenew =  'true' 
recurringSubscriptionInfo_startDate = *
recurringSubscriptionInfo_signaturePublic = *
orderPage_colorScheme = *
description = *
orderNumber = *
subscription_title = *
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but I believe you need to change orderPage_version to 7.
See http://drupal.org/node/1329896

Comment: I decided to carry on with "Installments" instead. Perhaps CyberSource updated their system because it creates 12 installments from the code segment I listed above and they are auto-captured when the time comes.